# Convert Custom Post Type Category into AMP

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using AMP plugin and i dont know how to convert category into AMP.

My CPT is movie-review and taxonomy is movie-category, I have successfully converted movie-reivew/abc-film/amp but don't know how to convert category pages.

Can you please help me out, i am using this plugin [AMP WP](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/amp/)

Comment: I think you are trying to get `http://localhost/test/movie-category/amp`. Is it?

Comment: Yes BlueSuiter exactly

Comment: `http://<site-url>/movie-category/` What this show?

Comment: its shows nothing

Comment: nothing or `404`. Is same happening with `movie-category`?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. its showing 404 error

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue of missing rewrite rules for the permalinks. Henceforth, you are redirected to 404. You have to define the rewrite rules for your custom taxonomy. Keep the following code in your theme's `functions.php` and reset the permalinks.

```
<?php 

    function addCustomTaxonomyRewriteRules()
    {
        //Rewrite rule for custom Taxonomies
        $args = array(
            'public'   => true,
            '_builtin' => false   
        ); 
        $output = 'names'; // or objects
        $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
        $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ); 
        if ( $taxonomies ) {
            foreach ( $taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {    
                add_rewrite_rule(
                $taxonomy.'\/(.+?)\/amp/?$',
                'index.php?amp&'.$taxonomy.'=$matches[1]',
                'top'
                );
                // For Custom Taxonomies with pages
                add_rewrite_rule(
                    $taxonomy.'\/(.+?)\/amp\/page\/?([0-9]{1,})\/?$', 
                    'index.php?amp&'.$taxonomy.'=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
                    'top'
                );
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('init', 'addCustomTaxonomyRewriteRules', 100);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. still showing 404 error on category page :(

/movie-category/new-movies/amp

Comment: Did you reset the permalinks??

Comment: I have updated the code please check now. Please, replace last function with this one. I can't test this code right now. So, you have to do this on your own. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks BlueSuiter,

Now its redirecting on the same page when i have added /amp. Also curious about this function will work when AMP plugin enabled right?

Comment: I have added you

Comment: By same page you means that it redirected on the required taxonomy page. Right? Also, please share if it is working with AMP plugin or not.

Comment: yeah you are right same page redirected... No its not working with AMP Plugin :(.. can we have a quick chat on skype?